# React components and module exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module

I don't understand how module.exports can only export one component that has a dependency on a subcomponent but still be rendered in the DOM although that sub component was never exported.

//component.js

```
var SubComponent = React.createClass({
...
    });

var Component = React.createClass({
    ...
    render: function () { 
    return(
        <div><SubComponent /> stuff</div>`)
        }});

module.exports = Component
```

//main.js

```
    var Component = require('./component.js');

    var MainContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function () {return (
    <Component />)
    }})
```

Answer (score 9):

You are using only one component directly (`Component`) in your `main.js` file. `SubComponent` is not used outside `component.js`, therefore it doesn't have to be exported. If you want to use `SubComponent` in your `main.js` file you could use it like this:

//component.js

```
(...)
module.exports = {
    Component: Component,
    SubComponent: SubComponent
}
```

//main.js

```
 var Component = require('./component.js').Component;
 var SubComponent = require('./component.js').SubComponent; (...)
```

Then you can use `SubComponent` directly in `main.js`

Comment: but looking at the original situation, how does component get rendered without subcomponent being exported at first? isn't subcomponent undefined in main.js because it was never exported? subcomponent is being used outside of component.js because it is part of Component

Comment: It works like a chain. `Component` can see `SubComponent` beacouse it is in the same fale. If you can see `Component` in main.js it is enough; only Component needs to see subcomponent in your case, MainContainer doesn;t care what is inside Component it only expects that it will render

Comment: If you're familiar with Java, think of non-exported modules as `private` variables, the class or file where it's defined can see it (i.e. `Component` can use `Subcomponent`, but other classes (i.e. other JS files) cannot.