# Reuse React components and module exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have a project A(see below), I build this project using "yarn build" and it generates main.js file. I want to use this main.js file as dependency for another react project B. (I followed: [React components and module exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860695/react-components-and-module-exports)) But it doesn't work. Is it the correct way to do this? Would you provide some suggestion?

Project A:

index.tsx

```
import { Home } from "./view/Home";

module.exports ={
    Home: Home
}
```

home.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import "../css/view/Home.css";
import { Background } from "../component/Background";
import { CL } from "../component/C";
import { DL } from "../component/D";


type Props = {
    P: number;
    Q: Array<string>;
    R: number;
    S: number;
    T: number;
    U: number;
}

export class Home extends React.Component<Props, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="home">
                <Background P={this.props.P}
                            Q={this.props.Q}/>
                <CL R={this.props.R}
                    S={this.props.S}/>
                <DL T={this.props.T}
                    U={this.props.U}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Project B

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import imagesPath from "./data/imagesPath.json";

var Home = require('./main.js').Home;

const transitionSettings = {
    P: 8000,
    Q: imagesPath,
    R: 55,
    S: 28,
    T: 5000,
    U: 23
}

function App() {
  return (
      <Home {...transitionSettings} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific reason to mix commonjs and ES6 modules it's better to stick with one way of declaring modules. And in ES6 modules you can re-export items in a different file to where it is declared with the `export { Thing } from "./Thing"` syntax.

Project A: `index.tsx`

```
export { Home } from "./view/Home";
```

And then in project B:

```
import { Home } from "./index"; // ES6 import

const transitionSettings = { ... }

function App() {
  return (
      <Home {...transitionSettings} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to "yarn build and provide main.js file to project B. I can not use Home.js directly.

Comment: what do you have in main.js

Comment: Can you explain where `main.js` comes from? All you've shown us from Project A is `home.tsx` and `index.tsx`. Assuming that `index.tsx` gets built into `main.js` then you should be able to just import te component from `main.js`. Unless there's somthing we're missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Project B` you can import the `Home` class directly by adding this line of code.

```
import { Home } from "./view/Home";
```

Just make sure you put the correct path for your file that contains the `Home` class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to "yarn build and provide main.js file to project B. I can not use Home.js directly.